# Configure installation of R in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, compiling, r

How can I install R in ubuntu with non default flags?

For example, for debugging, I would like to build R with the

```
-fsanitize=address
```

option. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be sufficient to set an appropriate `CFLAGS` environment variable before executing the configure script, e.g.

```
CFLAGS="-fsanitize=address" ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

The configure summary confirms

```
R is now configured for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

  Source directory:          .
  Installation directory:    /usr/local

  C compiler:                gcc -std=gnu99  -fsanitize=address
  Fortran 77 compiler:       gfortran  -g -O2

  C++ compiler:              g++  -g -O2
  C++ 11 compiler:           g++  -std=c++11 -g -O2
  Fortran 90/95 compiler:    gfortran -g -O2
  Obj-C compiler:        gcc -g -O2 -fobjc-exceptions

  Interfaces supported:      X11, tcltk
  External libraries:        readline, zlib, bzlib, lzma, PCRE
  Additional capabilities:   PNG, JPEG, TIFF, NLS, cairo, ICU
  Options enabled:           shared BLAS, R profiling

  Capabilities skipped:      
  Options not enabled:       memory profiling

  Recommended packages:      yes

configure: WARNING: neither inconsolata.sty nor zi4.sty found: PDF vignettes and package manuals will not be rendered optimally
```

and the additional flag is visible in `gcc` commands during the subsequent `make` e.g.

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -I. -I../../src/include -I../../src/include -I/usr/local/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -fopenmp  -fsanitize=address  -c integrate.c -o integrate.o
```

If you want to pass the flag to other compilers (such as the C++ or Fortran compiler) then you may need to set their equivalent flags `CXXFLAGS` and `FCFLAGS` as well: for a complete list you can execute

```
./configure --help | less
```

and look at the section titled `Some influential environment variables`.

Comment: Actually, one needs to change the `MAIN_LDFLAGS` flag (not the  CFLAGS). Can you edit your answer for future reader?